# How do I prevent bugs in JQuery animation

Tags: jquery, animation

I have a relatively simple animation using JQuery.

It is essentially boxes where one of them animates opacity from 1 to 0 and back again.
I want to pause the animation on mouseenter, and restart the animation on mouseleave, when entering or leaving any of the boxes.
I also change opacity of all the boxes on mouseenter, and change them back to the original opacity on mouseleave.

All of this works as I want it to, my problem is this:

When I quickly hover over different boxes, it would appear that i'm moving too fast for the different states of animation to keep up, and this in turn leads to buggy effects where opacity doesn't go back to its original state.

How are these bugs avoided?
I know the logic works correctly, it appears to be a performance issue.

Mouseenter and mouseleave logic:

```
$(".box").mouseenter(function() {
    $(".box").stop(true, false) // stop animation and stop queued animation
}

$(".box").mouseleave(function() {
    anim() // call anim function to restart animation
}
```

Working example:
https://codepen.io/JonnyPS/pen/pmQbaQ?editors=0010

Comment: Well, my first question would be, why are you doing a global selector inside each event handler, instead of just processing the logic on the element the event is for?

Comment: Hi Taplar, i have simplified the code for the example. In the real world situation every .box element will be animated on/off, but I think you may be right - I could just target ‘this’ instead in that situation